# Как узнать адрес электронной почты пользователя в Android

Tags: java, android

Я разрабатываю приложение для Android, и мне нужно получить почту используемую на телефоне и добавить её в
`webView.loadUrl("https://mysite.com/1/?get=" + get + "&get2=" + get2);`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то речь идет об активном аккаунте Google чтобы его почту использовать. Есть такой [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913527/how-to-get-current-active-google-play-account-in-android):

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
if(accounts != null && accounts.length > 0) {
    ArrayList playAccounts = new ArrayList();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        String name = account.name;
        String type = account.type;
        if(account.type.equals("com.google")) {
            playAccounts.add(ac.name);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Account Info: " + name + ":" + type);
    }
    Log.d("tag", "Google Play Accounts present on phone are :: " + playAccounts);
}
```

не забудьте прописать в манифесте разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Но вам нужно как-то определять что при условии если аккаунтов подвязано несколько, то брать тот что нужно. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) более подробно описано как работать с [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager)

Comment: Вместо электронной почты там пустая строчка.

Comment: если вы на эмуляторе это проверяете, то аккаунта там не будет, посмотрите под отладкой что вообще возвращает `AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts()`